# NodeJS script split into multiple files - require vs. import problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I have 2 files:

```
|- main.js
|- lib\
     |-  myLib.js
```

I added a Node.js package (camelcase in this case) to the project using NPM:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "camelcase": "^7.0.1"
  }
```

In myLib.js I need that the camelCase function coming from this package. The myLib script defines some utility functions used in main.js.

First, I tried to build the 2 files **without** including the "type":"module" to package.json:

```
// main.js
const myCamelCaseFn = require('./lib/myLib');
myCamelCaseFn ("do something");

// myLib.js
import camelCase from 'camelcase';

const myCamelCaseFn = (arg) => { return camelCase(arg); }
exports.myCamelCaseFn = myCamelCaseFn;
```

I got

> cannot use import statement outside a module

I read some pages, then I found out that this form of import only usable when "type":"module" is included to package.json. So I did it.

Then there were problems with the *require()* call, so I changed to the following:

```
// main.js
import {myCamelCaseFn} from './lib/myLib';
myCamelCaseFn ("do something");
```

Now I got

> cannot find module lib/myLib

So I changed to

```
const myCamelCaseFn = import('./utils/renamer.js');
console.log(myCamelCaseFn);
myCamelCaseFn ("do something");
```

I got

> myCamelCaseFn is not function

and I see the console message this is a `Promise { pending }`. As I read import function returns with a promise which will be resolved later - but I can wait to be resolved here (not needed using `Require()` as it works in another way). I changed again:

```
const myCamelCaseFn = await import('./utils/renamer.js');
myCamelCaseFn ("do something");
```

Now I got a different error message:

> ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope
> exports.myCamelCaseFn = myCamelCaseFn;

Continue reading it says exports and module.exports points to the same object. Later I got the following on Stack Overflow "Try and remove "type": "module" from package.json.".

Comment: You have to _pick one_ - either use ES modules with import (you can use the static form here, no need for the dynamic imports that use promises) and export, **or** CommonJS with require and (module.)exports. You can't mix and match. If you want to _consume_ ES modules, you have to use the former. Read e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import.

Comment: Yeah, I understand to pick one. But I have two problems: "include" my own script and use a "3rd party" lib. Neither syntax I can achieve both. One of them fails... :(

Comment: You're still using (module.)exports in your own script, **not** export. If you make your own code an actual ES module, using the right syntax, it will work.

Comment: Ok. Choose the CommonJS syntax. How to get the camelCase func from the package with dynamic import() in myLib.js? What is the right syntax?

Comment: If you choose CommonJS you can't import an ES module, and don't have dynamic imports, so that question makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as you encountered on your journey, there are two module systems in NodeJS, ESM and CommonJS. I will now demonstrate the correct code for either system.

## CommonJS

`main.js` can be left as-is:

```js
const myCamelCaseFn = require('./lib/myLib');
myCamelCaseFn ("do something");
```

`lib/myLib.js` is currently (mostly) in ESM format. You'd need to change it to use CommonJS format:

```js
const camelCase = require('camelcase');

const myCamelCaseFn = (arg) => { return camelCase(arg); }
exports.myCamelCaseFn = myCamelCaseFn;
```

However, this won't work, not because of any error in syntax from our code, but because the dependency, `camelcase` is written solely for ESM format.

## ESM

`main.js` is currently in CommonJS format. You'd need to change it to use ESM format. You also forgot the `.js` extension when you tried to change it to ESM format which was why it threw the "cannot find module" error:

```js
import { myCamelCaseFn } from './lib/myLib.js';
myCamelCaseFn ("do something");
```

`lib/myLib.js` is currently mostly in ESM format but its exports is declared incorrectly. You'd do something like this instead:

```js
import camelCase from 'camelcase';

export const myCamelCaseFn = (arg) => { return camelCase(arg); };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The ESM syntax is tested and works! But on the CommonJS in the myLib.js I still got the error "require() of ES Module not supported" for camelcase. is ther any chance to get it work?

Comment: @ZoltanHernyak again, and as that error clearly tells you, you cannot require ESM from CommonJS.

Comment: I found this: "Dynamic import() is supported in both CommonJS and ES modules. In CommonJS modules it can be used to load ES modules." so - is it possible to load ES modules (like camelcase) in a CommonJS script?